# What happens in Team Monobattles if my Infestor obtains a worker of a different race?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Team Monobattles a player is restricted to one attacking unit. It is possible to get or select Infestors. Then I can Neural Parasite an enemy worker to build a main building (Nexus, Command Center).

Given time and resources. Am I allowed to build the other players unit as well (e.g. Marine)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get to build probes, observers, SCVs and calldown MULEs. You can build every building you could ever imagine... and that is it.

The mod is built such that, all units are natively disabled until you choose the unit you want to play. So taking over an SCV will still have all military units disabled on the Terran tech tree.